# C++ Structure Initialization from cppreference.com

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to compile the below code but I always get mentioned error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* Name;
    char* Branch;
} st_employee;

st_employee details[3] =
{
    [0].Name = "XXX",
    [0].Branch = "YYY",
    [1].Name = "ZZZ",
    [1].Branch = "PPP",
    [2].Name = "III",
    [2].Branch = "LLLL"
};

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
c++ -x c -std=c11  -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread -pedantic-errors test.cpp -lm  -latomic  -Wmissing-field-initializers
```

Error:

```
test.cpp:44:5: warning: missing initializer for field 'Branch' of 'st_employee' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
     [1].Name = "Chennai",
     ^
test.cpp:22:11: note: 'Branch' declared here
     char* Branch;
           ^
test.cpp:45:5: warning: missing initializer for field 'Branch' of 'st_employee' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
     [2].Name = "Chennai"
     ^
test.cpp:22:11: note: 'Branch' declared here
     char* Branch;
           ^
test.cpp:46:1: warning: missing initializer for field 'Branch' of 'st_employee' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
 };
 ^
test.cpp:22:11: note: 'Branch' declared here
     char* Branch;
           ^
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Can you share link to the source?

Comment: The code is mentioned above

Comment: I think R2RT meant the cppreference.com page you based this on.

Comment: Using a C++ compiler with `-std=c11` is all kinds of weird.

Comment: The link is http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization - struct fred x[ ] = { { { "abc" }, 1 }, // inits x[0] to { {'a','b','c','\0'}, 1 }
                      [0].s[0] = 'q'   // changes x[0] to { {'q','b','c','\0'}, 1 }
                   };

Comment: That page is clearly about C, not C++

Comment: @FredLarson They are mentioned as array designators at the beginnings and somehow shown at the bottom of "nested initialization".

Comment: @Bob__: Ok, I found it. Not easy to see in all that crazy syntax.

Comment: @FredLarson Indeed, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) they are explained more clearly.

Comment: And [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) explicitly mentions this syntax as valid C, but invalid C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you linked is valid C11, not C++11. Since C and C++ are completely different languages, it won't compile using a C++ compiler.

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uzu5MOC2FgcUYR1i)

Comment: The use of `printf` is a bit of a giveaway too.

Comment: What is interesting clang handles it, but gcc does not: https://godbolt.org/g/oDjchC

Comment: Is it not possible to initialize in C++ like as mentioned in question - [0].Name etc?

Comment: @Prakash: simply put, no.

Answer (score 4):

In C++11, if the struct contained `const char*`'s, you could initialise the array like this:

```
st_employee details[3] =
{
    {"XXX","YYY"},
    {"ZZZ","PPP"},
    {"III","LLLL"}
};
```

Comment: No, conversion from string literal to `char *` is forbidden in C++.

Comment: Is it not possible to initialize like as mentioned in question - [0].Name etc?

Comment: Hmm, fair point @O'Neil - now to figure out why my compiler doesn't (at least) warn on that even with all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, in C++ you really should prefer [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) over raw character pointers / arrays and [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) container over raw arrays. Then simply use [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) to initialize your elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

struct st_employee {
    std::string Name;
    std::string Branch;
};

int main() {
    std::array<st_employee, 3> details = { "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ", "PPP", "III", "LLLL" };
    for (auto el : details) {
        std::cout << el.Name << ' ' << el.Branch << '\n';
    }
}
```